# Недаром говорят

Tags: пунктуация

Стоит ли ставить запятую в предложении:

Недаром говорят книга - это кладезь знаний.

Answer (score 2):

> Стоит ли ставить запятую в предложении:
>
> Недаром говорят книга - это кладезь знаний.

Лучше, по-моему, здесь будет смотреться двоеточие:

***Недаром говорят: книга - это кладезь знаний.***

Запятая уместна в таком варианте:

***Недаром говорят, что книга - это кладезь знаний.***

Comment: А что мешает поставить запятую?

Comment: См.: _§ 129. В бессоюзном сложном предложении между частями ставится двоеточие... 
3) если вторая часть бессоюзного сложного предложения имеет значение изъяснительное, что подчеркивается глаголами, помещенными в первой части предложения и предупреждающими о последующем изложении какого-либо факта..._ 
(http://orthographia.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=135#pp135 )

Comment: Слава, я прекрасно знаю это правило. Ср.: Говорят() он хорошо поет.. Что поставите?

Comment: Вот примеры из Национального корпуса.  Недаром говорят, опьянение от успехов…  [В. Емельянов. Все остается людям… // «Юность», 1971]  Недаром говорят, рыбаки водят дружбу с русалками! [И. И. Лажечников. Ледяной дом (1835)] И лапа очень быстро зажила, недаром говорят, «как на собаке! [Афанасий Мамедов, Исаак Милькин. Самому себе (2003) // «Октябрь», 2002 Недаром говорят, март не капелью, а метелью красен. [Александр Иличевский. Курбан-Байрам (2005) // «Новая Юность», 2004]

Comment: _Серж: Вот примеры из Национального корпуса..._ === Оттуда же: http://search-beta.ruscorpora.ru/search.xml?env=alpha&mycorp=&mysent=&mysize=&mysentsize=&mydocsize=&spd=&text=lexgramm&mode=main&sort=gr_tagging&lang=ru&nodia=1&parent1=0&level1=0&lex1=%ED%E5%E4%E0%F0%EE%EC&gramm1=&sem1=&sem-mod1=sem&sem-mod1=sem2&flags1=&m1=&parent2=0&level2=0&min2=1&max2=1&lex2=%E3%EE%E2%EE%F0%E8%F2%FC&gramm2=&sem2=&sem-mod2=sem&sem-mod2=sem2&flags2=bcolon&m2=

Comment: Слава, если вы имеете в виду примеры с двоеточием, я их видел. К тому же я и не отрицал постановку двоеточия в этом примере. Я говорил о приемлемости запятой. Всего  лишь.

Answer (score 1):

Запятая нужна после вводного выражения "недаром говорят".